# Installing windows beside ubuntu

Tags: dual-boot, kubuntu, windows-10

I installed ubuntu 20 on uefi settings on laptop. Now i wish to install Windows 10 in a separate partition. Here is my boot summary located on

> https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/nbrbgZt3hN/

Kindly guide me on setting up a dual boot system. I also wish to use a multiboot usb using ventoy

Comment: Make partition you want for windows NTFS format.  My limited experience says that Windows is not too bad by being installed second to Ubuntu on UEFI systems.  Would have Ubuntu install USB handy just in case needed to repair grub.  Update grub after Windows installation so grub can find Windows.

Comment: Be sure to boot installer in UEFI mode. Windows only installs in UEFI mode to gpt partitioned drives. It wants more than just a main c: "drive" partition. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/dn898510%28v=vs.85%29.aspx#RecommendedPartitionConfigurations All installs will share one ESP - efi system partition.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I figured out my problem. As I installed Ubuntu first, it placed `#` in front of `GRUB_TERMINAL=console`, thus not loading the dual boot menu prompting me to repairing grub several times without any luck.

Tips for anyone wish to install Windows beside Linux...

1. DO NOT ATTEMPT TO RESIZE,MOVE,USE RESTORE POINTS in Window MODE (USE LINUX LIVE cd instead) as Windows can't handle Linux partitions but Linux can handle both...
2. Because of (1), Precious data must always be stored in ntfs drives in a dual boot system because both Windows and Linux can access and protect them...
3. Installation order of UBUNTU AND WINDOWS may determine the automatic entries of GRUB (Correct if I am wrong)...